# Angular cli - ng new stuck

Tags: angular-cli

Angular cli doesn't generate new project with command below. Command line just stops doing anything and I'm redirected to new windows explorer window.

I tried reinstalling angular cli
Also tried reinstalling nodejs 
restarting PC

```
ng new new-app
```

There are no error messages, cli just hangs (tens of minutes).
Other commands such as ng serve, ng generate works ok.

I also tried suggested:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

That did not solve my problem.

Basically i have no idea what to do with the problem. Is there another option how to generate new angular project?

Comment: I don´t think its the same problem. I dont have any error messages. I also tried: npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Update Node Or Uninstall & install it {or npm cache clean --force}

then

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org"
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Try it in a new clean folder

Comment: I tried but the behaviour is still the same. All the angular cli commands seem to work but. ng new just opens windows explorer and nothing else happens.

Comment: try ng new my-app --skip-install , see if anything wrong with npm installation

Comment: It didn´t work even with skip install. Good news is that npm installation is ok i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your username folder, if there is package.json and node_module exist. If they are there then delete them.

Notice: you may have created an angular project in your home/username directory. If you delete them it will work.

Comment: User folder does not contain package.json or node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

Install the specific version (lower version) of Angular CLI using the below command and try again,

> npm install -g @angular/cli@version